# user not created in user manager using Federated Authentication

Tags: federated-authentication, user-management

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1. 
I've implemented federated authentication and it's working successfully. However, i have an issue that user creation always fails and i found the below error in the logs.

**"Cannot create user: InvalidEmail"**

After debugging for a while i found that this issue is caused when i change the below part in the web.config in order to make the email unique.

[image]

When i set the " requiresUniqueEmail" to false, it works but when i set it to true it fails in creating the user although i'm 100% sure that the current user email doesn't already exist before.

Any idea why does it fail when is set this parameter to true??

Comment: Are you sure email is mapped correctly?  If it is mapped to blank, this will quickly become a duplicate

Comment: @MarkCassidy yes email is mapped correctly. and i can read it using Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.Email or Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("User Email")